# create a context free grammar for speech recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, context-free-grammar, speech-to-text

We want to create a grammar file.  Is there any other way than `(hello|goodmorning)(jack|jill)`
to specify the probable set of first words then set of second words?

We are using it for recognizing speech from a video to generate subtitle .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure a CFG is the right model to use. Don't you need to associate each possible word in the ith position to a probability of it occurring? If so, then using a [PCFG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_context-free_grammar) is a bit better, but I think it can grow to become unmanageable very quickly. Why not use [HMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition#Hidden_Markov_models)'s as most people do?

See also: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~liam/teaching/neurostat-spr11/papers/hmm/rabiner.pdf